# Running 'commands' to install open source software

Tags: php, command-line, phpunit, pear

Not sure how to phrase the title of this question as not having a clue what i'm trying to describe is part of my problem. Here's what I mean: I often come across tutorials or open source software that will say something like this:

```
// Install PHPDocumentor
$ pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
$ pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-alpha

// Install phpunit
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

// Install Magento Ecommerce
svn checkout http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7
```

This may seem like a basic question, but where exactly do I enter these commands?

I'm using windows 7. If I attempt to enter these into the Windows Command Prompt I just get an error like 'xxx is not recognised as an internal or external command.'

It's frustrating because a lot of websites use these commands as instructions to install or upgrade their software.

I'm assuming the reason none of these websites explain where to run the code is because it's common knowledge, so sorry again if this is a basic question.

Comment: You need to install PEAR (look in the PHP install directory for `go-pear.bat`, which will take care of that) and [subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) (svn). You may find that many things don't work as smoothly as indicated in tutorials when you are running on Windows, though...

Comment: Oh windows, why must you hide the way computers actually work from people?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such tutorials often assume you are on a flavor of Linux, where the commands may commonly (but certainly not universally) be available because the relevant software was already installed.

You type the commands in from the Windows Command Prompt.  One way to start it is to click the START icon then type *cmd* in the text box that appears and press Enter.

[image]

[image]

You can download an installer for Subversion for Windows 7 from one of many companies that provide binaries.  Personally I use http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/ though there are several good alternatives.

To download pear for Windows 7 have a look at the following tutorial:

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-windows.html

Comment: In addition to Eric J's links, I'd suggest that when you look for how to do things, you make sure to add "Windows" to your search queries.  Things are different enough on Windows that you'll need to be using workarounds and hacks somewhat frequently.

Comment: Lots of good info here with the links, which will probably help the OP down the road, but you didn't include the answer to his main question about where to type `pear ...` and `svn ...`. Throw in something about the command prompt and you def got a +1 from me =)

Comment: @Windle: D'oh!  Totally meant to do that :-)  Updated.

Comment: @EricJ. No worries =) the screenshots are helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are for *nix shell, not windows.

But you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows for some, other have Visual Application .. like [TortoiseSVN](http://TortoiseSVN.net/) for SVN